# Using S4 object classes inside a parallel foreach

Tags: r, foreach, r-s4

I have the following code, which works:

```
library(foreach)
cl <- makeCluster(2)

registerDoSNOW(cl)


foreach(i = unique(iris$Species), .verbose = T , .multicombine = TRUE,  .packages = c("data.table"),
        .export = "jsonEntityField") %do% {
  subset <- iris[Species %in% i]
  candToEntityList(subset)
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

It basically composes long Strings and return them in a list. The function `candToEntityList(subset)` Extracts information from a table, returning a JSON in String format. Inside it creates instances of the class `jsonEntityField`, which is an S4 R class I made and which has the following syntax:

```
setClass("jsonEntityField", representation(name = "character", type = "numeric", ...))
```

These `jsonEntityObjects` are used to compose the json string. 
So far so good, but when trying to change `%do%` with `%dopar%` to make it parallel I get the error:

```
Error in e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data) : 
  unable to find variable "jsonEntityField"
```

If removing the `export`, the error: `Error in { : task 1 failed - ""jsonEntityField" is not a defined class"` is shown instead.

Does anyone have an idea of what is going on?

Comment: `setClass` is S4, not S3!

Comment: The error 'unable to find variable' is unrelated. It occurs whenever you explicitly export something that is not a valid object name (when using doSNOW backend)

Comment: Could you start a clean R session and reproduce the error - and then show the results of `ls()`?

Comment: Did you try to save `setClass("jsonEntityField", representation(name = "character", type = "numeric", ...))` in a variable, e.g. `jsonEntityField <- setClass("jsonEntityField", representation(name = "character", type = "numeric", ...))` and using `.export=c("jsonEntityField")` to load the variable on your slave? You should then create a new object with `jsonEntityField(name = "a", type = 1,...)`